# Custom Paypal credit card payment form required fields for payment api

Tags: node.js, paypal

I'm integrating a custom paypal credit card payment form in my project (Angular2 + Node.js).

Refer:

(1.) https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/credit-card-payments/#create-credit-card-payment

(2.) http://code.runnable.com/UXgyne_v2oZyAAC-/pay-with-a-credit-card-using-paypal-api-for-node-js

---

My question is do we really need to add "first_name" and "last_name" field in the form. Instead I just want to add one field for the name of card holder.

Please sugggest the best solution for my case. 
Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

Well actually you can do that. The name field are not compulsory.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a single field for Cardholder Name and then split it in your code so that you can populate first name and last separately.